# How do I check if values in a column are all equal to a given constant?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT student.name,student.major FROM
(student INNER JOIN grade_report ON student.student_number = grade_report.student_number)
WHERE grade_report.grade in ('A');
```

this gives me all the students who scored an A in any exam.

How do I query to get students who have only A's  in their grade report? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT student.name, student.major 
from student 
NATURAL JOIN grade_report
group by student.name, student.major 
having sum(grade_report.grade <> 'A') = 0
```

Group by the student and chose only those having non A grades equal zero.

Comment: It works, thanks. Also is there a way to get the same result using the keywords 'WHERE' and 'ALL' ?